# In DIVA-GIS, how do I set a .grd to show as containing continuous or categorical data?

Tags: diva-gis

I am running both DOMAIN and Maxent models on a set of raster data. In Maxent, I am able to set whether each dataset contains either categorical or continuous data. Is there a way to do this in DIVA-GIS before I run DOMAIN?

I have found this question in a few places, without any answers. I have read one thesis where the variable was set by using a hex editor, but that paper is over 10 years old.

Bottom line, I want to be sure the model is set up properly so I get the best results.